# To add web services in android is necessary the ksoap2....jar?

Tags: android, web-services

I am using android studio and I want to test the web service I create on .net 2010 in an android application but every tutorial or link I found is related with a "ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar" library. Is this library necessary to invoke a web service? or the android studio now provide a new way to call WS...
Thanks in advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after searching other methods to use web services I found that is not the only way, there are other ways, the thing is that ksoap2 had many helps, tutorials and continue in research... I commend it to use it.